# Datagrid to excel doesn't work with multiline headers

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I used this example to export data to excel from wpf datagrid http://kidaatlantis.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/data-export-from-datagrid-to-excel-in-wpf/

My datagrid is defined like this:

```
 <DataGrid Name="InputReportDataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" HeadersVisibility="Column" >
                    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Control">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="RedniBroj" />-->
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="UCode" Binding="{Binding Path= tblGood.UCode}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Good Name" Binding="{Binding Path= tblGood.Name}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Measurement&#x0a; Unit" Binding="{Binding Path= tblGood.MeasurementUnit}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Path= Amount, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Input Price" Binding="{Binding Path= InputPrice, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Input Value" Binding="{Binding Path= InputValue, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suggested Price" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedPrice, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suggested&#x0a; Value" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedValue, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vat" Binding="{Binding Path= VatBase}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vat Value" Binding="{Binding Path= VatValue, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suggested&#x0a; Value&#x0a; Without&#x0a; Vat" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedValueWithoutVat, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RUC" Binding="{Binding Path= SuggestedValueWithoutVat, Converter={StaticResource moneyConverter}}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Now when I don't use line breaks in my datagrid column headers everything works fine and data is exported to excel as it should be. But when I use line breaks, in my excel file every line break from my column header is recognized like separate column, so I have more columns than it should be and, of course, my data is not sorted as it should be. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Let me get your situation right... *you* used someone else's code to do *your* work for you and now under a particular circumstance, that code doesn't work and so *you* want someone else to fix the code that *you* didn't write, so that *you* don't have to... does that sound about right? My first suggestion to you is to *never use code that you don't understand*. My second suggestion is for you to show the relevant parts of the code that you didn't write... we're good on this website, but we're *not* mind readers.

Comment: @Sheridan +1! You read my mind :D

Comment: With all due respect sir, that was a little bit rude. Reading your comment seems like I didn't put any work and research to solve my problem and that really is not true. As young and inexperienced developer it's impossible in some point to write own code to solve some problems, so what you gonna do? Look for some tutorial on google of course. Yes I don't understand the code in full but I have a deadline for this so I most care about to make it work. And about relevant parts of the code I didn't write, I left the link didn't I? So those critics really don't help me. How would you feel?

Comment: And also the link that I posted really don't have enough information to understand the code in full. So I cant come here and ask the question like: "Can anybody explain this code to me?". I tried to use this code by myself and try my best to understand and make it work, but I couldn't so I came here and asked for help on particular problem, ain't this site all about that or I'm wrong? So, I'm sorry again but next time when criticizing me think about how is it when you are on the begging of your career? I'm not a genious I'm aware of that.